# Solving treeview long information form user experience

Tags: input-fields, user-centered-design

[image]

Hello everyone,
I am facing this issue while working on a long form consisting of large number of metadata fields within headers. Would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks !

Comment: Hi. Welcome. It's unclear what the problem is and what question you'd like us to answer. Could you edit your question to describe the problem and why you feel your own alternatives have failed?

Comment: The question seems to be about form nesting but it isn't really answerable the way you've put it. Can you try to be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a lot of data that represents a single object.  That's not an uncommon starting place.

As you build out the first couple fields, putting them all in the same context makes sense, but as the complexity of your data structure grows in size, you'll likely need more than one context to properly display and edit *all* the information for a particular object.

Here's an example of how to structure deeply nested and complex sets of information from IIS, each into different areas of information

[image: IIS Example]

The temptation to put everything on a single page so you have a single dashboard that knows everything often ignores the process of doing BA / UX work on different workflows and screens.  Users prefer simplicity and clear delineations as to what group of data they are interacting with at each moment in time.

Even if power users want a high level view of *everything*, they can't physically look at >1 page of scrollable content at one moment in time. Providing everything at once can fall into the anti-pattern of **Data Rich, Information Poor** (**DRIP**) AKA - when [everyone's super, no one is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rwx7m.png)

Comment: Thanks Kyle alot, your right breaking it into some chunks of information and grouping it.